# Why is the interleave_view missing in the range-v3 library?

Tags: c++, range-v3

In Eric Niebler's range-v3 calendar example he uses interleave followed by chunk to transpose a matrix.

I wonder why interleave is not part of the range-v3 library...

Comment: you can raise that issue with Eric Niebler [here](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/issues). Better yet you can even fork from his library and implement the function yourself. Hence the power of open-source software.

Comment: See https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/issues/776

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lack of time, and some unsolved design difficulties. For instance, what does it mean to interleave ranges of different lengths? That wasn't a problem in the calendar example, but it's a question that needs to have an answer before the interleave view can be part of range-v3.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification - for my purposes I want to transpose a matrix - so all ranges have the same lengths. 
I copied your interleave_view from the calender example to [link](https://wandbox.org/permlink/p3Z02FAzcgGNBD8n).
Unfortunately, the direct transpose via `vector<vector<int>> n_x_m_matrix = m_x_n_matrix | interleave() | chunk(n_cols);` is slower than `vector<int> vec_temp = m_x_n_matrix | interleave(); vector<vector<int>> n_x_m_matrix_fast = vec_temp | chunk(n_cols);`

Comment: Interleave for ranges of different size: I would suggest that `[1, 2, 3, 4],[a, b, c],[I, II, III, IV, V]]` interleaves to `[1, a, I, 2, b, II, 3, c, III, 4, IV, V]`.

Comment: That is a sensible way to interleave ranges of different sizes, but implementing that comes with runtime cost, if I remember correctly.

Comment: Wouldn't it be a sensible design choice to have a policy to decide what to do with ranges of different sizes? Like a CutShort policy, stopping a the shortest range, a Best effort, interleaving as much as possible until the longes one is exhausted like Porsche9ll mentiones, and maybe a specialization for ranges with all DefaultInitializable values so after you run out you insert default initialized type (Or a supplied value for each range.